# Linkedin API: How to activate r_basicprofile as a permission?

Tags: json, linkedin-api

According to the official LinkedIn documentation, r_basicprofile should be accessible to ALL developers:

[image]

And yet, on my app default permissions, I can't see it:
[image]

Consequently, the calls to

> https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me

return

```
{
  "serviceErrorCode": 100,
  "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /me",
  "status": 403
}
```

How can we activate the basicprofile permission?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The r_basicprofile permission is no longer available after [the migration from v1 to v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context) of the API effective May 1, 2019.  As far as I know, there is no way to request access to it any longer.  Instead, you only have access to the three permissions listed in your screenshot.  There are "Enterprise Application" [developer programs](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/products) like the Marketing Developer Program, but you have to fit the exact use case and receive approval from LinkedIn to participate.  It appears that some of the LinkedIn documentation is out of date and can confuse the issue quite a bit.  Here is [another article](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates) that may be helpful.